# Is the expression "cake cutting "suitable when cake is sliced on special occasions?

Tags: word-usage, usage, grammar-myths

In India on the special occasions like on 'birthdays and anniversaries cake is cut and this act is described as below 1)The birthday girl cut the cake
2)The cake was cut
3)Cake cutting ceremony etc. What are the expressions used by native users for the above expressions??

Comment: In the UK we use the same sort of phrase. It is a tradition at weddings.

Answer (score 1):

At traditional British weddings, the moment may be called:

- *Cake Cutting*
- *Cutting The Cake*
- *The Cutting of the Cake*

You'll find the first two names used interchangeably in [this article](http://www.weddingservices.eclectic-choice.co.uk/Wedding-Catering/cutting-the-wedding-cake.htm). Examples of the latter are used [here](https://www.1gateau.com/the-cutting-of-the-cake/) and [here](https://www.purephotoni.com/blog/wedding-traditions-the-cutting-of-the-cake).

You don't always have to use these *names* for the ceremony. You could describe the ceremony by saying, for example, "*they cut the cake*". Wedding officials will tend to use the formal language and make announcements such as "please be upstanding for the cutting of the cake".